# sqlite3_bind_xxxx, sqlite3_column_xxxx - first parameter

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I have the following statement:

```
SELECT title, price FROM table WHERE id=?
```

Should I use to bind ID:

```
sqlite3_bind_int(myStmt, 0, current_id);
```

or do I have to use:

```
sqlite3_bind_int(myStmt, 1, current_id);
```

My question is - what should be the first binding parameter - 0 or 1?

The same question about getting data with sqlite3_column_xxxx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html), “The leftmost SQL parameter has an index of 1.”

However, for [`sqlite3_column_xxxx`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html), “The leftmost column of the result set has the index 0.”